# Searching an excel with two search words (multiple lookup) using vba macro

Tags: vba, excel, lookup-tables

I am using vba macros.
Task: 
1) User will give two inputs viz. number of devices sold (column B) and week number (column A).
2) Search the excel file using these two and get the earnings.
(Conditions: 
1. We dont have to modify anything in the excel file.
2.And we have to first search `devices sold` and then we can go to `week number`.)

Note: Actually i have a different problem, this is generalization for that.
I used `find` function but I dont understand why its working.

Please tell what is to be done.
Consider the input is `11` and `week 3` (so search for `11` and then check if its corresponds to `week 3` or not. If not, move to next. I tried this but ended up in an infinite loop.)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a **Lookup with multiple criteria**. A quick search gives several useful links, listed below. I have marked with * those that I have answered.
I have filtered out some of the links that actually deal with other issues.

As seen in the links, there are **several options** to achieve your goal. I personally prefer those that **do not need array formulas**, using [an answer to question 1 with `LOOKUP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9064042/2707864) or [an answer to question 2 with `SUMPRODUCT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967291/2707864).

Since you mentioned that you need a VBA solution, you can use `WorksheetFunction` to use an Excel formula in VBA code, or check answers to question 7.

1. [Multiple Column vs Multiple Column Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058672/multiple-column-vs-multiple-column-lookup)  *
2. [Multiple-column based lookups in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965329/multiple-column-based-lookups-in-excel)  *
3. [Lookup Database (Multiple criteria)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942687/lookup-database-multiple-criteria)
4. [Excel Lookup with multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096095/excel-lookup-with-multiple-queries)
5. [Multiple VLOOKUP LOOKUP IF Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641248/multiple-vlookup-lookup-if-statement)
6. [Returning a value if three columns match in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359430/returning-a-value-if-three-columns-match-in-excel)  *
7. [VLookup multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925313/vba-vlookup-multiple-columns)
8. [Comparing two columns in one Excel sheet, to two columns in another sheet, and if they match, copy data from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409376/comparing-two-columns-in-one-excel-sheet-to-two-columns-in-another-sheet-and-i)  *
9. [Macro for vlookup with 2 vertical criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822201/macro-for-vlookup-with-2-vertical-criteria)  *
10. http://spreadsheets.about.com/b/2014/01/08/excel-lookup-formula-using-multiple-criteria.htm
11. http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list
12. http://blogs.office.com/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas/
13. http://www.xl-central.com/lookup-multiple-criteria.html
14. http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/05/22/lookup-multiple-values-in-different-columns-and-return-a-single-value/

PS: The (probably partial) list of (probably) duplicated questions provided above shows the usefulness of what was proposed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211366/group-duplicate-questions-for-convenience

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any VBA for such a simple thing. Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX(C2:C5;MATCH(1;(B2:B5=11)*(A2:A5="week 3");0))
```

Dont forget to enter the formula with Ctrl Shift Enter (it is an array formula)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate week and number of devices and then search like usual one keyword search.