# Vlookup to check two conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I am referring to below my google spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dCfShenhV2j98q5wkOXMeyWj9tlMZbaBgBqB2vAPdHo/edit?usp=sharing

I am looking to update `H,I and J` columns using vlook formula in way that it should match both `name` and `date` values in my data range, which in `A,B and C` columns

Here is the issue I am facing with normal vlookup is that I can check only name.It is ignoring the date and updating the vlooked up data on all date column.

Eg: `Alpha` and date `20141120` value is 10, it should fill only `H3`, but it is updating, `H3` `I3` and `J3` with value 10

I really appreciate your answer on this problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this formula of **index** and **match**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$C,MATCH(1,($A:$A=$G3)*($B:$B=H$2),0),3),"")
```

paste it in the first cell of your table ***H3***, and drag and fill to the right and then select the entire row and fill down till end.
it should work.

`if error(();"")` : you will get empty cells if there is no match.

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula

***UPDATE***: here is [the example sheet downloadable from here}(https://www.dropbox.com/s/clqxsj5j4bdk27b/indexmatch.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: it works for me, maybe you are not pressing ctrl+shift+enter or your cell references are different from the ones in the formula.

Comment: worked after cleaned up the tab and re-created..thanks for the quick help

Comment: If I want to show another value instead of empty cell for no match, how can I edit it ? I want to use value 100, and when I am editing the last portion "H2=M3"), getting error circular refernce

Comment: what is H2=M3 about? where do you put it?
you can put **100** inside that **" "** , so replace it with **"100"**. the you will get 100 instead of empty cells.

Comment: I trying to add another formula, instead of showing it as blank, gor example, get the dara from cell M2 into H2 (H2=M2)

Comment: write your complete formula here and let us see what it is like.

Comment: Can you please let me know why this same formula is not working here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5W4CgZKsARFUlQ2c0dfVENhaWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the reason is that you are refering to data!B$2, and this is wrong. you should refer to data!B$1, because this cell contains your date. in my example, H$2 refers to the date, because it is in the second row, but in your excel file the dates are in the first row. so change it to data!B$1 and then ctrl+shft+enter, then drag and fill to the right then drag the entire row and fill down till end. tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed it now and changed. Now it is working but it take some time to update all cells. Is that excepted behavior with this formula or can I do something to calculate it fast

Comment: no it is normal, because you are using array formula and data retrieval from another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to concatenate the results, then use a VLOOKUP on that.

I.e. insert a column between B and C, with formula "=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)"

In the range you want to update, use the column and row headings for you lookup
"=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($g3,h$2),$c$1:$d$3,2,false)"

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform a *Multiple Lookup* (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21582535/2707864)).
As indicated there, enter

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$A$3=$G3)/($B$1:$B$3=H$2),$C$1:$C$3),"")
```

in H3. Copy into H3:J5.

This avoids array formulas.