# how to match two sheets with random data

Tags: excel

sheet 1

```
     PNR    AMT    
1   H2JUFL  2343
2   W9CGJJ  4397
3   K9IC8T  12770
4   C9NL2Q  17707
5   K4NG2S  10584
6   MYVIVD  5769
```

sheet 2

```
     PNR    AMT
1   K9IC8T  12770
2   C9NL2Q  17707
3   MYVIVD  5769
4   H2JUFL  2343
5   K4NG2S  10584
6   W9CGJJ  4397
```

How do I reconcile the data in the two sheets to see if the data matches or not?
First row is the pnr no. and the second row is amount for that pnr.
I would like to first match the pnr and if that is true then match the corresponding amount and state "ok" if true and if false show amount of sheet 2
and in case if pnr of sheet 1 is not present in sheet 2 then state no entry

I have tried `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(a1,sheet2!$aD$1:$a$6,1,FALSE)),"no entry","")`. This works for pnr. but I am unable to go further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) to retrieve the associated AMT on **Sheet2** and compare them. If the numbers match then **OK**, otherwise report the different number. In Sheet1!C2 use the following formula.

```
=IF(B2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE), 1E+99), "OK", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE), "No Match"))
```

Fill down as necessary. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: VLOOKUP and compare]

I have intentionally changed the AMT in Sheet1!B4 and the PNR in Sheet1!A6 to show different scenarios.

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) has been used to catch non-matches.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data in both sheets start at A2.
You have several options:

1. Perform a [multiple lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21582535/2707864) (here in the form of a multiple `MATCH`).
2. Build a helper column in sheet1 (use `=A2&B2` in C2, copy downwards), and `MATCH` it with a concatenation from each row in sheet2 (use `=MATCH(A2&B2,sheet1!$C$2:$C$15,0)` in C2, copy downwards). You may use a helper column in sheet 2 with a concatenation, and use it for matching.